# MySQL SELECT query syntax - not working as expected?

Tags: php, mysql

I can't seem to get this to work,

Basically, what I want to do is return all the rows in which the column `timestamp` is more than the variable `$timestamp`, and the column `hit_counter` is less than the column `max_hits`.

Getting the first part to work isn't a problem, but the second part seems to be, as it still fetches rows when `hit_counter` is more than `max_hits`.

**Here's my code:**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE timestamp >= '$timestamp' AND hit_counter >= 'max_hits' AND overflow = 'NO'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$size = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

That seems to return all the correct rows for `timestamp`, however still continues to select rows where `hit_counter` is more than `max_hits` (even though it shouldn't select any at all  as `>=` is more than or equal to), while to inverse `>=` to `<=` returns no results, even though mathematically, it's valid.

I think perhaps I'm referencing `max_hits` as a value incorrectly, as I don't understand why it's working in the first place?

I know my question is a little iffy, so if you need any clarification please, do ask :).

Any answers/help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

I've updated the query as per the many great answers below, (removing the '' encasing `max_hits` and changing `>=` to `<=` but it still returns rows which are not meant to be included by the query.

Here's a pastebin to my full code: http://pastebin.com/V4vXJr1w

Here's a link to my table structure: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AoELUDjfbpSXdEUybkgwQmpxUnVCWlZOZnFJdzFaQmc&hl=en_GB

Comment: Hang on a second, what are you expecting `hit_counter >= max_hits` to return? You seem surprised that it's returns results where hit_counter is greater than max_hits...but that's exactly what you've asked. Sorry if I'm missing something, would you mind clarifying?

Comment: @mwan100: Changing `>=` to `<=` returns no results in this instance, at least `>=` was returning results, the reason why, and the problem is the fact that `max_hits` is encased in single quotes, i.e. interpreted as a string, as has been pointed out in the answers below :).

Comment: Can you give us a little more info about what rows are being returned?  Do you get the same number of rows if you leave the hit_counter bit out entirely?

Comment: @Alan Moore: I get a different number of rows, but it continues to change. For example, even though all rows in the database had `hit_counter` values higher than `max_hits`, the first time I echoed `$size` it would return 1, the second `0`, which then trips `if($size == 0)` and for some reason the script on a perpetual loop (keeps reloading the page).

Comment: ANother question, are max_hits and hit_counter both setup as int fields in the database structure?

Comment: I've just been playing around PHPMyAdmin and I've edited the fields, I've managed the script to return the correct numbers for `$size`. I've also realized that I'm not using `header()` to redirect, but echoing html, which makes more sense when I think about the looping.

Comment: Post the SQL DDL for the table, sample data as SQL insert statments, and your expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it will work if you remove quotes around 'max_hits':

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE timestamp >= '".$timestamp."' AND hit_counter <= max_hits AND overflow = 'NO'";
```

the problem being that you are referring to the string 'max_hits' instead of the column value.

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE timestamp >= '$timestamp' AND hit_counter <= max_hits AND overflow = 'NO'";

Comment: Still doesn't work :(. I've updated my OP with a little more information, I've been trying to get to the bottom of this infernal code (knocking kinks out) for like 3 hours, hopefully this'll be the final issue :). I've you'd like to take a look, it would be VERY much appreciated :), if not, thanks for your input anyway :)!

Comment: I don't know if this will matter, but you might try wrapping the $timestamp -- I'll change my code to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE timestamp >= '$timestamp' AND hit_counter >= 'max_hits' AND overflow = 'NO'";
```

If max_hits is a column, you need to lose the quotes.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE timestamp >= '$timestamp' AND hit_counter >= max_hits AND overflow = 'NO'";
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but it still doesn't work (also `>=` should be `<=` :)). I've updated my OP if you'd like to take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Two things look wrong to me at a glance.

1. If you want to compare one column against another you don't want to quote the column name, mysql just see's that as comparing your hit_counter column against the string 'max_hits'.
2. Also perhaps I'm misunderstanding you, but I think you've got one of your greater than signs backwards. It should roughly be:

   SELECT * FROM links WHERE timestamp >= '$timestamp' AND hit_counter < max_hits AND overflow = 'NO'

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm looking for, but it still doesn't work :(. I've updated my OP if you'd like to take a look? Thanks for your input ;).